# "Act in a certain way" or "act a certain way"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When I should put "in" after the verb "act"?
I occasionally see some don't put "in" between "act" and "a certain way". Example:

1. *"But you must **act in a certain way**, so that you can appropriate what is yours."*
2. *"We don't have to **act a certain way**."*

Also I have a problem with using "the/this/that way" with "act", because some put "in" between them, however, others don't!

Comment: @tchrist Almost always, yeah, they're the same. But isn't there some need for adding "in" sometimes?

Comment: @NVZ You can act — meaning, conduct or comport oneself — **in** a professional manner. You cannot omit *in* there.

Comment: You can say it the right way, or in the right way.  But such questions are better asked on the sister site for English language-learners, http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: One can also "act accordingly".

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the proper phrase includes the preposition *in*. The word is often omitted, however, because its absence doesn't change the phrase's meaning.

You act in such a way, act in accordance to, etc.